# Will selecting from table 1 into a temp table before joining with table 2 help a query run faster?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have table 1 with 50,000,000 rows

I left join it to table 2 with 100,000,000 rows

The query runs slowly. That doesn't surprise me as both tables are large.

When I examine table 1 I see that I only need 39,000 rows from it.

If I were to select those 39,000 rows into a temp table, then join the temp table with table 2, would it help my query run faster?

Does Postgresql somehow optimize my query to a similar effect?

My join on fields are indexed, but some of my where clause fields are not indexed.

My table indexing, counts, and current slow query are below.

Thanks!

```
 schemaname | tablename  |            indexname            | tablespace |                                         indexdef
------------+------------+---------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 schema1    | table1     | idx_table1_ind1                 |            | CREATE INDEX idx_table1_ind1 ON table1 USING btree(field2)
 schema1    | table1     | pk_table1                       |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pk_table1 ON table1 USING btree (id)
(5 rows)

iii=> select * from pg_indexes where tablename = 'table2';
 schemaname | tablename |               indexname               | tablespace |                                                indexdef
------------+-----------+---------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 schema2    | table2    | idx_table2_ind1                       |            | CREATE INDEX idx_table2_ind1 ON table2 USING btree (field3)
 schema2    | table2    | idx_table2_ind3                       |            | CREATE INDEX idx_table2_ind3 ON table2 USING btree (field6)
 schema2    | table2    | pk_table2                             |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pk_table2 ON table2 USING btree (id)
(5 rows)

iii=> select count(id) from table1;
  count
----------
 50,442,468
(1 row)

iii=> select count(id) from table2;
   count
-----------
 107,978,483
(1 row)

select
table2.field1,
count(*)
from table1
left join table2
on table1.field2 = table2.field3
where 1=1
and extract(year from cast(table1.field4 as date)) = 2018
and extract(month from cast(table1.field4 as date)) = 1
and table1.field5 = 'foo'
and table2.field6 = 'bar'
group by table2.field1
```

Explain results:

```
  QUERY PLAN

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=2945968.78..2945968.88 rows=10 width=40) (actual time=22526.520..22526.543 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2945968.77..2945974.93 rows=616 width=40) (actual time=22526.515..22526.531 rows=11 loops=1)
         Group Key: varfield.field_content
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..2945965.69 rows=616 width=40) (actual time=15151.373..22343.986 rows=102148 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on circ_trans  (cost=0.00..2870045.85 rows=59 width=8) (actual time=15151.324..17935.922 rows=102147 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((item_agency_code_num = 9) AND (date_part('year'::text, ((transaction_gmt)::date)::timestamp without time zone) = 2018::double precision) AND (date_part('month'::text, ((transaction_gmt)::date)::timestamp without time zone) = 1::double precision))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 50371955
               ->  Index Scan using idx_varfield_record_id on varfield  (cost=0.57..1286.68 rows=10 width=48) (actual time=0.014..0.040 rows=1 loops=102147)
                     Index Cond: (record_id = circ_trans.bib_record_id)
                     Filter: ((marc_tag)::text = '245'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 26
 Planning time: 0.528 ms
 Execution time: 22527.076 ms
(13 rows)
```

Comment: **1)** `and table2.field6 = 'bar'` This will turn your LEFT JOIN into a plain join. **2)** And: you could possibly rewrite this into a BETWEEN (or similar):  `and extract(year from cast(table1.field4 as date)) = 2018
and extract(month from cast(table1.field4 as date)) = 1`

Comment: Show the results of `EXPLAIN` on your join query please.

Comment: @eurotrash, I edited my post to include explain results. The actual table/field names are showing in that. In my original post I change names.

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output, please.And the table definitions, including indexes in readable form. [ it appears that `transaction_gmt` is a text column? ]

Comment: Looks like the seq scan on `circ_trans` that's slow. (A seq scan on 50 million records will, well,be very slow.) Can you refactor your query on that table to use any indexes? Or maybe you need some more indexes? Maybe an index on `item_agency_code_num` would be sufficient, if that number tends to be different mostly from one record to the next.

Comment: @wildplasser, ok, this time including explain analyze.

Comment: @eurotrash, I don't have admin control to create new indexes.

Comment: `circ_trans  (cost=0.00..2870045.85 rows=59 width=8) (actual time=15151.324..17935.922 rows=102147 loops=1)` First step compare expected <<-->> observed. BINGO!

Comment: @wildplasser, I'm not sure I understand. It looks like the 'seq scan on circ_trans' shows actual time is slow - 18 sec - that was to get the circ_trans data. Apparently slow, because of the lack of indexing. The join to the second table - Index Cond: (record_id = circ_trans.bib_record_id) - was fast, because the fields were indexed. I'm guessing a temp table based on circ_trans won't help, because the analysis shows postgres is already filtering that table first - Rows Removed by Filter: 50371955. If I'm wrong, can you post an answer?

Comment: I can do nothing without the actual table definitions, etc. And data-types are important, too. So are semantics, and cardinality. Pesonally, I can hardly think of a query where the join-field is **not** a FK->PK reference, for example.

Comment: @wildplasser, what did you see that made you say "BINGO!" ?

Comment: `rows=59` vs `rows=102147`: the planner chose a wrong plan because of **1)** lack of alternatives **2)** lack of information, or **3)** bad information.